# Windows Backup failed with error 0x807800C5 incorrect function

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup, freenas

This is the same error number as [similar post](https://superuser.com/questions/508932/windows-backup-failed-with-error-0x807800c5), but not the same details

[image]

This is on a Windows 10 machine trying to backup to a FreeNas network location. Part of the backup completes (user files) but fails at the image backup with `incorrect function`.

Has anybody found a way to correct this problem in windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be caused by Windows only allowing one system image to be backed up
to NAS. Windows 10, unlike older versions, is incapable of overwriting or deleting
the first system image, so causing the second image backup to fail.

If this is your case, you can resolve this issue by either:

1. **Renaming the original backed up system image**
   Gain access to the NAS shell and rename the original system image from `__nas_backup_WindowsImageBackup_host-name` to `__nas_backup_WindowsImageBackup_host-name.bak`.
2. **Rename the backup folder**
   Find the location of the `WindowsImageBackup` folder located on the NAS, say `f:`, then rename `F:\WindowsImageBackup` to `WindowsImageBackup.old`.

Comment: I deleted the original directory, created another directory with different name, same issue. Another thing that is strange, the windows machines have no problems backing up to a Ubuntu Samba file share. I only had the problem when i starting trying to use FreeNas as the target network location.

Comment: Does FreeNas still use the outdated SMBv1? Try in Control Panel / Programs and Features / Turn Windows features on or off, check "SMB 1.0 CIFS File Sharing Support", OK and reboot.

Comment: SMB 1.0 CIFS File Sharing Support previously enabled.

Comment: I have seen reports (but don't have FreeNas to check) that mention problems when the FreeNas "Server Maximum Protocol" setting is set to SMB3 and up, fixed by changing it to SMB2_22 (or SMB2_02 or SMB2?), requiring rebooting of both the FreeNas & Windows. Another report said to use a network folder without access restrictions, so Windows will not require user name and password for the folder. In any case, Windows system image backup is is very problematic and I would really recommend using instead the free
[AOMEI Backupper Standard](http://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html).

Comment: I'm going to have to schedule a time for more test. I'm setting this up on production machines for a company and can't reboot or make major changes unless by schedule. I like the looks of AOMEI but I'd have to go with the ~$450 option to support all systems this is affecting. So I'll have to do more troubleshooting and consider hosting a Ubuntu share before I can convince the client to foot the bill. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get some downtime with the Windows Machines and FreeNas and was not able to figure out what, if anything needed to be changed to prevent Windows from having this problem.

To get around the issue, I created a tiny Ubuntu Server VM Samba Share, mounted the FreeNas backup directory to that machine, and then shared that folder via Samba to the Windows machines. Windows backup now works as expected and is performant enough (~40GB initial full backup with system image over the network in 15min 11sec) for the clients needs.